# Why is db:migrate failing when i try to add attachment fields for paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip

I am trying to add two different attachment fields. The migration is failing wether i run it using bundler or without. (bundle exec rake db:migrate or just rake db:migrate).

```
==  AddDiagramToQuestion: migrating ===========================================
-- change_table(:questions)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `has_attached_file' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Table:0x0000012b003b20>
 /Users/kboon/Documents/workspace/quiztaker/db/migrate/20111213182927_add_diagram_to_question.rb:6:in `block in up'
 /Users/kboon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:244:in `change_table'
```

The migration looks like this:

```
class AddDiagramToAnswer < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :answers do |t|
      t.has_attached_file :diagram
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_attached_file :answers, :diagram
  end
end
```

The model also references methods added by paperclip and the app runs fine so its not that paperclip isn't installed at all. I've even tried added require 'paperclip' to the migration but that didn't help at all.

Comment: is the paperclip gem in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: Yes, I should have said that explicitly. has_attached_file works just fine in my models too

Comment: what version of paperclip u are using ?

Comment: The error is saying `20111213182927_add_diagram_to_question.rb:6` but your posted migration is for `answers` rather than `questions`. Have you posted the correct migration file here?

Comment: One way around it is using of explicit migration generated by `rails g paperclip question diagram`.

Comment: I have two migrations, one that adds a diagram to question and one for answer but they are identical. I created the explicit migrations for now but I still wonder why my migration didn't have access to the helpers.

Comment: Does it help to have `require "paperclip"` in your migration file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The migration that was created for me doesn't use the t.has_attached_file terminology anymore, it actually adds the columns explicitly. The migration would be created by running:

```
rails generate paperclip Answer diagram
```

Check out the example [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Usage).

Comment: This is what I ended up doing even though the documentation still uses the has_attached_file method.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
def change
  create_table :some_table do |t|
    t.attachment :avatar
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Migration file should be look like

```
class AddDiagramToAnswer < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_attachment :answers, :diagram
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :answers, :diagram
  end
end
```

or

```
class AddDiagramToAnswer < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.attachment :avatar
    end
  end
end
```

has_attached_file is used in model.rb(answer.rb in your app)

> with rails 5