# Migration of RubyOnRails 5 to 6.0.1: db:migrate creates no tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am migrating a RoR app and issue the following command, so whats all this `ActiveRecord` errors:

```
leder@home-ryzen-desktop:~/Git/gmr_production_heroku$ ./bin/rails db:migrate
== 20170111144155 CreateArticles: migrating ===================================
-- create_table(:articles)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
/home/leder/Git/gmr_production_heroku/db/migrate/20170111144155_create_articles.rb:6:in `block in change'
/home/leder/Git/gmr_production_heroku/db/migrate/20170111144155_create_articles.rb:3:in `change'

Caused by:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)
/home/leder/Git/gmr_production_heroku/db/migrate/20170111144155_create_articles.rb:6:in `block in change'
/home/leder/Git/gmr_production_heroku/db/migrate/20170111144155_create_articles.rb:3:in `change'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This is the `20170111144155_create_articles.rb`:

```
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :text
      t.has_attached_file :attachment

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

when I add `arel` gem like this accepted answer:

[arel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389629/ror-tutorial-section-5-5-dbmigrate-error)

I get the error here:

[error_paste](https://pastebin.com/djRS3TiE)

**One update:** gems are installed for ruby version 2.7.1 and not my current version 3.0.1. Is this due to a previous `chruby` installation and not my `rbenv`?

Comment: Hint: `See full trace by running task with --trace`

Comment: Hi @max! As you can see in the command in "error_paste" there is already a `--trace`

Comment: Is your app using the paperclip gem?  If so it is deprecated: really not sure if it will work under rails 6.  Thoughtbot's advice is to use Activestorage in its place.  Also regard your 2.7.1 vs 3.0.1 have you run rbenv rehash?

Comment: This post may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8964611/why-is-dbmigrate-failing-when-i-try-to-add-attachment-fields-for-paperclip

Comment: so `ActiveStorage`: looks like a lot of work for two small websites... here we go! BTW `rbenv rehash` at the right moment did the trick!